# Howto specify own robots.txt rules for LWP::RobotUA

Tags: perl, robots.txt, lwp

I wrote a script to check my own websites with LWP::RobotUA. I would like to avoid the frequent requests for my robots.txt.

The rules parameter for LWP::RobotUA should allow me to specify those, but I don't qiute understand what should be passed for "allow all pages".

```
my $ua = LWP::RobotUA->new(agent=>'my-robot/0.1', from=>'me@foo.com', rules=> ??? );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I think the intended way to supply robots rules is by subclassing WWW::RobotRules.

```
{
    package WWW::NoRules;
    use vars qw(@ISA);
    use WWW::RobotRules;
    @ISA = qw(WWW::RobotRules::InCore);

    sub allowed {
        return 1;
    }
}

my $ua = LWP::RobotUA->new(agent=>'my-robot/0.1', from=>'me@foo.com', rules=>WWW::NoRules->new);
```

Answer (score 1):

LWP::RobotUA is LWP::UserAgent with `robots.txt` support added. If you do not want to request `robots.txt`, then just use LWP::UserAgent.

Alternatively, subclass LWP::RobotUA and override the `simple_request` method and strip out `robots.txt` and rule handling.